# Matching columns to retain result data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a complete list of all sample ID's in column 1.

Column C shows the samples that have been tested for pH (and thier corresponding result in column D)

[image]

Column B is a duplicate list which inserts blanks using the following VBA code:

```
Sub Listduplicates()

Dim rngA As Range
Set rngA = Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
rngA.Offset(0, 1).Columns.Insert
With rngA.Offset(0, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-1],C[1],0)),"""",INDEX(C[1],MATCH(RC[-1],C[1],0)))"
    .Value = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

The question: How do I now get the pH result (column D) to match with its corresponding Sample ID in column A?

Answer (score 0):

Fit a dictionary with Column C as key and Column D as value, then scan down column A filling in the values from dictionary to column C and D.

```vb
Sub Listduplicates()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
   Dim dict As Object, key As String
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All Data")
   With ws
       ' scan col C get results from column D
       lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = 2 To lastrow
           key = Trim(.Cells(i, "C"))
           If dict.exists(key) Then
               MsgBox "Duplicate SampleID '" & key & "'", vbCritical, "Row " & i
               Exit Sub
           ElseIf Len(key) > 0 Then
               dict.Add key, .Cells(i, "D").Value2
           End If
       Next
       
       ' scan col A
       lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       For i = 2 To lastrow
           key = Trim(.Cells(i, "A"))
           If dict.exists(key) Then
               .Cells(i, "C") = key
               .Cells(i, "D") = dict(key)
           Else
               .Cells(i, "C") = ""
               .Cells(i, "D") = ""
           End If
       Next
   End With
   MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```